# Exclude module docstring in autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to use autodoc in Sphinx to print out the docstrings of every functions in a specific module but exclude the module's docstring. Is it possible?

The reason is that I'm using the modules docstring to specify command line options (with the lovely docopt).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to **conf.py**:

```
def remove_module_docstring(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
    if what == "module" and name == "yourmodule":
        del lines[:]

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-docstring", remove_module_docstring)
```

This code removes the module docstring in the `yourmodule` module by providing a handler for the [autodoc-process-docstring](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event.

Comment: I chose to make the docstring to a variable by just adding ```docopt_string = ```.