# How do I selectively hide module docstrings in sphinx autodoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

In autodoc, I know you can hide the docstrings for *all* modules as described here:
 [Exclude module docstring in autodoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927741/exclude-module-docstring-in-autodoc)

But is there a way to do this for some modules and not others, possibly with some parameter passed to `automodule`? In other words, for a given module, I want to sometimes include the docstrings and sometimes skip it. If I do:

```
.. automodule:: foo
   :members: foo, foo.bar
```

Sphinx generates the docstrings for foo and foo.bar. However, doing

```
.. automodule:: foo
   :members: foo.bar
```

will not hide the module docstring.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is in the linked answer. The code in that answer does not hide the docstrings for **all** modules; it only hides it for the module called `yourmodule`.

Comment: @mzjn thanks! What you say is correct but that code in conf.py applies to all instances of a module in a given project. For example, in some files, I'd like to exclude the docstring. In other files, I'd like to keep it.

Comment: But you could expand the code in my answer and use something like `if what == "module" and name in ("module1", "module2", "module3"):`. Wouldn't that work? Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the docstring of a module, you use the corresponding plain `py` domain version of the directive: either [`py:module`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:module) or [`py:currentmodule`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:currentmodule). The former is for the main place you document the module, and should only occur once. The latter is for other places where you want the same name resolution properties, but without making it the official documentation spot for the module.

All the `autodoc` domain directives will respect the naming scope set by the regular `py` domain directives. From the docs:

> **Note**
>
> Just as [`py:class`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:class) respects the current [`py:module`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:module), [`autoclass`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoclass) will also do so. Likewise, [`automethod`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automethod) will respect the current [`py:class`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:class).