# Exclude header comments when generating documentation with sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to use `sphinx` to generate documentation for my python package. I have included well documented docstrings within all of my functions. I have called `sphinx-quickstart` to create the template, filled in the template, and called `make html` to generate the documentation. My problem is that I also have comments within my python module that are also showing up in the rendered documentation. The comments are not within the functions, but rather as a header at the top of the `.py` files.  I am required to have these comment blocks and cannot remove them, but I don't want them to show up in my documentation.

I'm current using `automodule` to pull all of the functions out of the module. I know I can use `autofunction` to get the individual functions one by one, and this avoids the file headers, but I have a lot of functions and there must be a better way.

How can I adjust my `conf.py` file, or something else to use `automodule`, but to only pick up the functions and not the comments outside of the functions?

This is what my `.py` file looks like:

```
"""
This code is a part of a proj repo.

https://github.com/CurtLH/proj

author: greenbean4me
date: 2018-02-07
"""

def hit(nail):

    """
    Hit the nail on the head

    This function takes a string and returns the first character in the string

    Parameter
    ----------
    nail : str
       Can be any word with any length

    Return
    -------
    x : str
       First character in the string

    Example
    -------
    >>> x = hit("hello")
    >>> print(x)
    >>> "h"
    """

    return nail[0]
```

This is my the auto-generated documentation looks like:

```
Auto-Generated Documentation

This code is a part of a proj repo.

https://github.com/CurtLH/proj

author: greenbean4me date: 2018-02-07

hammer.hit(nail)

    Hit the nail on the head

    This function takes a string and returns the first character in the string

    nail : str
        Can be any word with any length

    x : str
        First character in the string

    >>> x = hit("hello")
    >>> print(x)
    >>> "h"
```

For a more comprehensive example, check out this example repo on GitHub: https://github.com/CurtLH/proj

Comment: What you call "header comments" are module-level docstrings. Here is a way to exclude them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031024/407651.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to configure autodoc not to do this.

There is, however, a simple workaround: Adding an empty docstring at the top of your module.

```
""""""  # <- add this
"""
This code is a part of a proj repo.

https://github.com/CurtLH/proj

author: greenbean4me
date: 2018-02-07
"""
```

It's barely noticeable, and will trick autodoc into not displaying your module's real docstring.

Comment: Keep in mind this will also remove the module docs from `help()`.